# My object is faulty in Unity. How can i fix this?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, object, unity-container

The bar in the brick breaking game goes through the walls. I have tried many times to fix this but without success. Box collider, rigid boddy looks fine. My codes are at the bottom and I have uploaded the video to youtube for better understanding of the error. Thanks.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgITYLgu84g

My Code;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rightcontroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody rb;




    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        bool RightArrow = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow);
        bool LeftArrow = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow);

        if (RightArrow)
        {
            Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
            tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + tempVect);
        }

        if (LeftArrow)
        {
            Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
            tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + tempVect);
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: It's better to post code directly (within code blocks) than to provide a link. Also better to state your problem, rather than post a link to a youtube.

Comment: I typically use raycasts for this type of interaction.  If left arrow, cast a ray to the left (if right, cast to the right) at a distance of movement and test if it hits the wall.

Comment: If you have colliders and a rigidbody on the ball it will not leave

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the walls have colliders? If so, make sure `IsTrigger` is NOT enabled. Also make sure that the bar has a collider with `IsTrigger` unchecked.

Check your collider to see if it is in the correct place and size.

If none of those work, then there is something wrong with the way you structured your scene, in that case we would need more information.